# Regex to match exact text and any suffix OR other text?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a **domain** and if matches to also check a specific tld.
If **domain** doesn't match then suffix can be anything.

The regex is: `^(?(?=(gmail))\1\.com|.*)$` Which works well, but not in Python
But the problem is Python does not support Branch Reset Group.

What would be a solution to this?

For example:

```
-google.fr -> true
-gmail.com -> true
-gmail.fr -> false
```

Link: https://regex101.com/r/6KZ81f/13

Comment: Do you have a list of domains you want to match, or do you plan to run an individual Regex findall for each specific domain?

Comment: I don't think your pattern uses a branch reset group. If you are referring to `(?` I think that is an If clause. Your current pattern uses a positive lookahead for the if clause. If that succeeds, then match group 1. Perhaps use a negative lookahead `^(?:(?:gmail|yahoo)(?!\.fr)|google(?=\.fr))\..*` https://regex101.com/r/Srp0Kb/1

Comment: I'm planning to have individual regex, but wanted to get an answer for a specific need/use case

Answer (score 2):

You can use negation, for example

```
^(((gmail.com))|(?!gmail).*)$
```